# Populate form via URL :id using ReactJS and Flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I need to populate a form via the URL :id parameter, so that the user can edit the author name. I'm getting the following error when i click in the link to the author name:

[error when i click the author name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV7Qk.png)

The view of the author form is in the AuthorForm.js, just like this:

```
function AuthorForm(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
        <TextInput
          id="name"
          name="name"
          label="Name"
          value={props.author.name}
          onChange={props.onChange}
          error={props.errors.name}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" className="btn btn-primary" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

The props are being passed by the parent component ManageAuthorPage.js

```
const ManageAuthorPage = (props) => {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [redirectNotFound, setRedirectNotFound] = useState(false);
  const [authors, setAuthors] = useState(authorStore.getAuthors());
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState({
    id: null,
    name: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    authorStore.addChangeListener(onChange);

    const id = props.match.params.id;
    if (id === undefined || authors.length === 0) {
      authorActions.loadAuthors();
    } else if (id) {
      setAuthor(authorStore.getAuthorById(id));
    }

    return () => {
      authorStore.removeChangeListener(onChange);
    };
  }, [props.match.params.id, authors.length]);

  function onChange() {
    setAuthors(authorStore.getAuthors());
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Manage Author</h2>
      <AuthorForm
        errors={errors}
        author={author}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default ManageAuthorPage;
```

I'm also, using Flux, so my authorStore looks like this:

```
class AuthorStore extends EventEmitter {
  /**this will allow React components to subscribe to our store
   * so they're notified when changes occur */
  addChangeListener(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

  /** this will allow React components to unsubscribe from our store*/
  removeChangeListener(callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }

  emitChange() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  }

  getAuthors() {
    return _authors;
  }

  getAuthorById(id) {
    return _authors.find((author) => author.id === id);
  }
}
```

I also have the authorAPI, which have some methods too:

```
export function getAuthorById(id) {
  return fetch(baseUrl + id)
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
      return response.json().then((authors) => {
        if (authors.length !== 1) throw new Error("Author not found: " + id);
        return authors[0];
      });
    })
    .catch(handleError);
}
```

My author data looks like this:

```
"authors": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Cory House" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Scott Allen" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Dan Wahlin" }
  ]
```

How can i fix this? I think that the error is in the getAuthorById in the AuthorStore, but i don't what to do exactly.

Also, sorry for my bad english, this is my first question here.